# Flycheck package status obsolete

Tags: macos, emacs, eslint, flycheck

I am trying to integrate Flycheck into my emacs. I installed Flycheck `exec-path` and `js-standard` through the package manager.

[image]

My `.emacs` file contains:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

;; https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell
;; only need exec-path-from-shell on OSX
;; this hopefully sets up path and other vars better
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

I have a `.eslint` file in the same home location as my `.emacs` (`.bash_profile` as well) on unix osx yosemite.

How can I fix this obsolete status and run Flycheck. I apologize in advance for being new to linting my code, low level emacs user here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs marks packages as “obsolete” if a newer version of the package is loaded.  Emacs never loads obsolete versions, thus obsolete versions may safely be removed.  Go to the package menu in `M-x list-packages`, then type `~` (mark obsolete packages for removal) and then `x` (execute actions).  Alternatively type `U` and `x` to conduct a full upgrade of all packages which includes removal of any obsolete packages.

---

In any case the “obsolete” status doesn't have any impact on the package at all: It'll continue to work normally.

If Flycheck does not work for you, please ask a new question about Flycheck specifically, and include all [debugging information](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/contributor/contributing.html#bug-reports).  Note that there's a dedicated [Emacs community](https://emacs.stackexchange.com) on StackExchange where you question is better placed.

Comment: thanks i ended up using your solution from the emacs community as well for implementing basic in browser flycheck

[flycheck-with-relative-file-eslint-exec](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21205/flycheck-with-file-relative-eslint-executable/21207#21207?newreg=9b5e5fdeab664ecabd4a65860e232edd)